# How to set puppet environment in puppet-rspec test?

Tags: rspec, puppet

Is the error message below actually talking about the "environment" for puppet?  If so, how do I set the enviroment for these types of test?

**update** see comments on system environment(gems and puppet version) at the end of question

I have a manifest [now given in full] :

```
# == Class: iop_alfresco_tomcat
#
# installing a Tomcat that is customised for running Alfresco cluster node
# uses some customised local rpm packages for base tomcat software, keys
# and software dependancies for Alfresco.  Does not install war file with
# Alfresco in it
#
# === Parameters
#
# all defaults are for the dev2 environment
#
# *cluster_hosts*
#
# list of the names of the hosts that make up the cluster
#
# *cluster_name*
#
# *solr_host*
#
# host that is running the solr indexer.  See iop_solr module
#
# *database_uri*
#
# *database_user*
#
# *database_pass*
#
# these parameters are to connect to the postgresql database that Alfresco
# depends on.  See iop_alfresco_postgresql module
#
# === Authors
#
# James Andrews 
#


class iop_alfresco_tomcat(
  $version='4.1.2.17',
  $clusterhosts=['tomcat1rmc-dev2.ourdomain.com',
                  'tomcat2rmc-dev2.ourdomain.com'],
  $clustername='rmcdev2',
  $solr_host='solrrmc-dev2.ourdomain.com',
  $database_uri='THISISAURL',
  $database_user='IAMAUSER',
  $database_pass='ABC123',
  $owner_user='services_dev'
) {


  file {'/etc/init.d/alfresco-tomcat':
    source => 'puppet:///modules/iop_alfresco_tomcat/alfresco-tomcat',
    owner  => 'root',
    group  => 'root',
    mode   => '0755',
    }

  package { ['alfresco-tomcat', 'alfresco-test-keystore',
              'swftools', 'openoffice']:
    ensure=>'installed'
  }


  $tcv = '7.0.55'


  exec { 'link_tomcat':
    command => "/bin/ln -s /usr/local/alfresco-tomcat-${tcv} /usr/local/tomcat",
    creates => '/usr/local/tomcat',
    require => Package['alfresco-tomcat']
  }

  file {'/usr/local/tomcat/alf_data':
    owner   => $owner_user,
    ensure => directory
  }

  file {'/usr/local/tomcat/alf_data/keystore':
    ensure  => symlink,
    replace => yes,
    force   => true,
    target  => '/opt/alf_data/keystore',
  }

  file {'/usr/local/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties':
      content => template('iop_alfresco_tomcat/alfresco.properties.erb'),
      owner   => $owner_user,
      require => Package['alfresco-tomcat']
      }

  file {'/usr/local/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/web-extension/custom-slingshot-application-context.xml':
      content => template('iop_alfresco_tomcat/custom-slingshot-application-context.xml.erb'),
      owner   => $owner_user,
      require => Package['alfresco-tomcat']
      }

  file {'/usr/local/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/module/settings/':
    ensure => 'directory',
    recurse=> true,
    owner  => $owner_user
    }

  file {'/usr/local/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh':
    source => 'puppet:///modules/iop_alfresco_tomcat/setenv.sh',
    owner  => $owner_user
  }

  file {'/usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml':
    content => template('iop_alfresco_tomcat/server.xml.erb'),
    owner  => $owner_user
  }

  file {'/usr/local/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/module/settings/alfresco-global-dev2.properties':
    path   => '/usr/local/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/module/settings/alfresco-global-dev2.properties',
    owner   => $owner_user,
    source => 'puppet:///modules/iop_alfresco_tomcat/alfresco-global-dev2.properties'
  }




  exec {'set rmc.target':
  command => '/bin/echo \'rmc.target.platform=dev2\' >> /usr/local/tomcat/conf/catalina.properties',
  unless  => '/bin/grep \'rmc.target.platform=\' /usr/local/tomcat/conf/catalina.properties',
  require => Package['alfresco-tomcat']
  }

  file { '/usr/local/tomcat':
    path    => '/usr/local/tomcat/',
    links   => 'follow',
    owner   => $owner_user,
    recurse => true,
    require => Package['alfresco-tomcat']
  }



}
```

I am using an "environment" called "alfrescodev2", not the "production" environment
On the servers to apply the manifests during testing I would say something like

```
    puppet agent -t --environment=alfrescodev2
```

Test for the above manifest (this is simpler than in the original question):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "iop_alfresco_tomcat" do

it { should compile.with_all_deps }

end
```

I am trying to run this in a directory with a checked out copy of the module in it. The modules for the alfrescodev2 environment are also checked out.

I should explain this further: it's a r10k based system and the environments are in git branches.  I have the branch for this environment checked out

The host I am running it on is not a puppetmaster.  Our system also uses hiera

This is the error I get

```
$ rake rspec
/opt/puppet/bin/ruby -I/opt/puppet/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-support-3.1.2/lib:/opt/puppet/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib /opt/puppet/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\*\*\{,/\*/\*\*\}/\*_spec.rb

iop_alfresco_tomcat
  example at ./spec/classes/iop_alfresco_tomcat_spec.rb:5 (FAILED - 1)

iop_alfresco_tomcat
  example at ./spec/fixtures/modules/my_module/spec/classes/iop_alfresco_tomcat_spec.rb:5 (FAILED - 2)

Failures:

  1) iop_alfresco_tomcat 
     Failure/Error: it { should compile.with_all_deps }
     Puppet::Error:
       Could not parse for environment production: No file(s) found for import of '' at line 4 on node tomcat1rmc-dev2.ourdomain.com
     # ./spec/classes/iop_alfresco_tomcat_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) iop_alfresco_tomcat 
     Failure/Error: it { should compile.with_all_deps }
     Puppet::Error:
       Could not parse for environment production: No file(s) found for import of '' at line 4 on node tomcat1rmc-dev2.ourdomain.com
     # ./spec/fixtures/modules/my_module/spec/classes/iop_alfresco_tomcat_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Ok, I did some further investigations.  I got a different, older module that had a rspec test that had been previously working on a different system.  On that other system the older modules rspec tests still worked.  I copied the old module source to the system that is the problem described in this question.  When I ran it, the same type of error `Could not parse for environment production: No file(s) found for import of ''` occurred.  To me this seems to say that there is something incorrect with the way that the puppet is set up on the system described in this question.  So, here is some info on the software on the system

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.1.0)
deep_merge (1.0.0)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
hiera-puppet-helper (1.0.1)
io-console (0.3)
json (1.5.5)
metaclass (0.0.4)
minitest (2.5.1)
mocha (1.1.0)
net-ssh (2.1.4)
puppet-lint (1.1.0)
puppet-syntax (1.3.0)
puppetlabs_spec_helper (0.8.2)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.5)
rspec (3.1.0)
rspec-core (3.1.7)
rspec-expectations (3.1.2)
rspec-mocks (3.1.3)
rspec-puppet (1.0.1)
rspec-support (3.1.2)
rubygems-update (2.4.2)
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
$ /usr/local/bin/puppet --version
3.4.3 (Puppet Enterprise 3.2.0)
$ cat /etc/issue
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

Comment: Oh, Puppet **Enterprise**? Does that not come with a bundled version of `Ruby`? I never tried that - might be that `gem list` does not apply to what Puppet sees at all. FWIW, the options from the `rake` job do look as though they should be fine for PE, but there might be hidden issues.

Answer (score 2):

That should not pose a problem. Yes, `rspec` will use the default environment, but during [setup](http://rspec-puppet.com/setup/), you should have made the module under test available in `spec/fixtures/modules`, where `rspec` will look it up.

It might be a problem that you are using `spec/classes/iop_alfresco_tomcat_spec.rb` but describing `permissions`. Try and

```
describe 'iop_alfresco_tomcat_spec' do

end
```

if this is indeed your class name. (Not sure if this is a show stopper, though.)

Comment: I checked the instructions for fixture setup, did all the things suggested and I am getting the same error.  Altered the describe name like you suggested and I'm getting the same error.  So thanks for the suggestions but they didn't seem to work

Comment: Do you have an `import "$some_variable_that_is_empty_in_rspec_context"` or other weirdness in the code you are testing(?) Puppet is failing pretty hard here, would likely need to see more of the manifest to advise further.

Comment: There are no funny imports and as far as I know nothing clever in the manifest.  I have now included the init.pp the only manifest file in full in my question.  I have altered the test to be simpler, the same error occurs.